# Append lines to a previous line

Tags: awk

I am trying to append all lines that begin with > to the previous line that did not begin with >

```
cat tmp

ATAAACGGAAAAACACTACTTTAGCTTACGGGATCCGGT
>Aa_816
>Aa_817
>Aa_818
CCAAACGGAAAAACACTACTTGAGCTTACGGGATCCGGT
>Aa_940
>Aa_941
CTAAAAGGAAAAACACTACTTTAGCTTTTGGGATCCGGT
```

What I want is this:

```
ATAAACGGAAAAACACTACTTTAGCTTACGGGATCCGGT >Aa_816 >Aa_817 >Aa_818
CCAAACGGAAAAACACTACTTGAGCTTACGGGATCCGGT >Aa_940 >Aa_941
CTAAAAGGAAAAACACTACTTTAGCTTTTGGGATCCGGT
```

This almost gets me there:

```
cat tmp |awk '!/>/ {sub(/\\$/,""); getline t; print $0 t; next}; 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '!/^>/{printf "%s%s", (NR==1)?"":RS,$0;next}{printf "%s", FS $0}END{print ""}' file
```

Comment: You should always provide a format specifier for printf: `printf "%s%s", (NR==1)?"":RS, $0` and `printf "%s", FS $0` -- this protects you if the string to be printed contains %-directives.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk '!/>/{printf (NR==1)?$0:RS $0;next}{printf FS $0}' file
```

If you don't care the output has new line generated on the first line, here is the shorter one.

```
awk '{printf (/>/?FS $0:RS $0)}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is a little `sed`:

```
sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n>/ >/g' file
```

Results:

```
ATAAACGGAAAAACACTACTTTAGCTTACGGGATCCGGT >Aa_816 >Aa_817 >Aa_818
CCAAACGGAAAAACACTACTTGAGCTTACGGGATCCGGT >Aa_940 >Aa_941
CTAAAAGGAAAAACACTACTTTAGCTTTTGGGATCCGGT
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[^>]/ { if (length(old) > 0) print old; old = $0 }
     /^>/    { old = old " " $0 }
     END     { if (length(old) > 0) print old }'
```